# How much data transferred from PostgreSQL to Redis in one batch is considered reliable?

Tags: postgresql, redis, scalability

In a scalable system, I frequently need to query data from PostgreSQL and cache it in Redis. I wonder how much data can I transfer at once, and when do I need to consider making multiple batches or using message queue.

One use case is that when a user login, I want to cache all user ids of the user's friends to Redis. We're a social platform so a user may have a lot of friends, 1K, 10K or even more.

So when the user logs in, I need to do something like below (Python for example, but the question should be language unspecific)

```
cur = pg_conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = ?', user_id)
friend_ids = [item['friend_id'] for item in cur.fetchall()]
cur.close()
redis.sadd('%s.friends' % user_id, *friend_ids)
```

My question is, at what magnitude of data could this piece of code handle. Let's say friend_id is a UUID (36 bytes), how many friend_id could I query at most, that this piece of code can reliably transfer these ids from PostgresSQL to Redis?

What are the factors that could affect the upper limit of the data transfer size? Assuming both the application server, PostgreSQL and Redis are running in the same region of AWS.

By reliably, I mean the code above does not likely to fail (> 99% or 99.9% or so), but don't need to be as reliable as a bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to redis documentation:
https://redis.io/commands/sadd

> Available since 1.0.0.
>
> Time complexity: O(1) for each element added, so O(N) to add N
>   elements when the command is called with multiple arguments.

SADD is very performant and would not depend on the current size of the redis key, you can't improve this performance (by modeling / changing query...), it is already the best possible!

It means only network (mostly ping time between redis and your server, you can measure that) and size of N do matter (mostly because of network bandwith usage).

Redis is mono-threaded so only one SADD is being processed at a time, you would need very big inserts (lots lots of elements to insert, I feel 10k does not seem so impressive) to slow down redis. In most cases you are more worried about getting out of memory on redis (that you should supervise).

These parameters depend only on your infrastructure quality which should be great (or you can easily improve it by changing your servers / vpc on your cloud provider).

If really you are worried about the size of the payload on the network, you can use a lua script that will do the SADD command and zip the payload before calling redis and unzipping it inside the script, it should decrease your network load.

For reliability, it is best if you use some kind of auto-retry process to put to redis if the first SADD fails for whatever reason (see circuit breaker pattern for instance).